# How to classify data relative to line using Python? Left or right side of a line

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, classification

I want to classify the data relative to line. If the point is on the left side of the line than it has a symbol -1. If the point is on the right side of the line than it has a symbol +1.

Data

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np



A=make_moons(n_samples=1000, noise =.05)
B=make_moons(n_samples=1000, noise =.3)
C=make_moons(n_samples=200, noise =.05)
D=make_moons(n_samples=200, noise =.3)
```

My attempt at classification for set A

```
#any line
x = np.linspace(-1,1,100)
y = 2*x

points=[-2,-4,3,6]
left_side=[]
right_side=[]
line_vector=[5,10]
for i in range(0,1000):
    vector=[A[0][i,0]+2,A[0][i,1]+6]
    determinant=np.cross(line_vector,vector)
    if determinant<0:
        left_side.append([A[0][i,0],A[0][i,1]])
    else:
        right_side.append([A[0][i,0],A[0][i,1]])
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work entirely well.
The first figure shows the data after classification. The second figure is the original data.

Output

[image]

Comment: For each point in the data find the point on the line with the same (or similar) y value then check if the data point's x value is greater than or less than the x value of the line's point. Please read [mre] - how could we evaluate  your process without a minimal example of the data you are operating on?

Comment: Why are you adding `[2, 6]` in creating `vector`? Your classification has an offset error,  and you add a mysterious offset, so these may be related.

Comment: I used it [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/274712/calculate-on-which-side-of-a-straight-line-is-a-given-point-located). Now I have noticed that I made a mistake, because I should add [2,4]